# how to write formula as a worksheet function

Tags: vba, optimization, formula, theory

I have a big loop that iterates over a 1000 data loads.. instead of doing this as efficiently as possible (saving output to an array and then printing at the end), I have been writing values to the worksheet then copying and pasting to another sheet for each run.

I have a couple questions both theoretical and practical.

1. Is it faster to continue copy/paste for each line except do so within the current worksheet and then copy and paste the final data table at the very end?
2. How can I rewrite this function as a worksheetformula. The reason why I dont currently use an array is I dont know how to rewrite this formula as a non cell formula.

```
Dim avg_rng As Range
Set avg_rng = Sheets("OrdCloseTrade").Range(Cells(strt_pt(end_ct), j), Cells(end_pt(end_ct) - 
1, j))
'Debug.Print sum_rng

Sheets("OrdCloseTrade").Cells(47, lent + 2).FormulaArray = _
"=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & avg_rng.Address & ")," & avg_rng.Address & "))"
```

Comment: what do you want the output of that UDF(user-defined function) to be?

Comment: avg_rng is a range of numbers and potentially #VALUE errors. I want to write a function like this array function that will be performed and saved internally without writing to the sheet.. I think this will make the program run faster. The output should be an average over the range excluding error values.

Comment: also by function I was referring to the .FormulaArray.... not a separate VBA function

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite get your first question.

But the less copy-and-paste actions, the faster the execution.

For the second question, perhaps the following could give you a hint.

```
Function avgVal(ByVal rng As Range)
    avgVal = Application.Evaluate("=average(if(isnumber(" & rng.Address & ")," & rng.Address & "))")
End Function
```

The function takes a range as an argument and output the average. So you can use it in a cell by calling

`=avgVal(A1:D1)` for example

Comment: ok awesome... yeah thats exactly what I was looking for ".Evaluate"

Comment: I tried putting 3 in A1, 4 in B1 #REF! in C1 and 9 in D1

finally, E1:  `=avgVal(A1:D1)` gives 5.5333

so it seems okay